# Conflict with tikz using LaTeX3's keys module

Tags: tikz-pgf, expl3

I want to use LaTeX3 to set some parameters for node, but something goes wrong, mwe is as follows

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,xparse,expl3}
\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\test}{m}
{
    \group_begin:
    \keys_set:nn{test}{#1}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[\tl_use:N \l_node_argument_tl]{test~text};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \group_end:  
}
\keys_define:nn{test}
{
    node.tl_set:N = \l_node_argument_tl,
}
\test{node=draw}
\test{node={draw,circle}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

The following information is displayed in my terminal

```
Package pgfkeys: I do not know the key '/tikz/draw,circle' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

I understand that tikz treats "draw,circle" as a whole, but I don't want that, how should I do it,thanks!

Comment: Try `\use:x { \exp_not:N \node [ \exp_not:V \l_node_argument_tl ] }`

Comment: To add a little detail, pgfkeys splits its input into separate keys _before_ it considers whether any need expanding.  So you need to expand your token list before it gets read by pgfkeys.  There are a variety of ways of doing this, Phelype's is quite a good one.

Comment: While @PhelypeOleinik's comment works, better and more reliably would be `\exp_args:NNV \node [ \l_node_argument_tl ]`.